MAUI - How to add runtime permission for Bluetooth
I'm trying to connect to BLE sources and I see thaat I need to ask runtime permissions to user for BLUETOOTH_SCAN..
My runtime error is
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for
    AttributionSource { uid = 10363, packageName = com.test.myapp, attributionTag = null, token =  
    android.os.BinderProxy@c225240, next = null }: GattService registerScanner'

This is my AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission androi`your text`d:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />

I've tryied to set them in code but
    PermissionStatus status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
    status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Bluetooth>();
    status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

status is always GRANTED.
What can I do? If I set manually after install on my device the "Nearby devices" for the app... all works fine, but if possible I don't want to do  outside the app.
I want the app to ask user to set permission.

You can try the following code, it works on my side.
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //PermissionStatus status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
        //status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Bluetooth>();
        //status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

        PermissionStatus status = await CheckAndRequestBlueToothPermission();

        if (status.Equals(PermissionStatus.Granted))
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("permission grant", "Tip", "OK");
        }
    }

    public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestBlueToothPermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Bluetooth>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)

            return status;
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            // Prompt the user to turn on in settings

            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permission,please turn on in settings ", "Tip", "OK");
            // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
            return status;
        }

        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale < Permissions.Bluetooth>())
        {
            // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permission", "Tip", "OK");
        }
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Bluetooth>();

        return status;
    }

